# Getting posts from users using facebook sdk and flask

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, flask

I followed few examples I found online to let people login to my site, which worked, but when I tried to fetch their posts I got stuck.

I try to get posts like this (on my `@app.before_request`, where I handle tokens and check if user is new one or old):

```
        postss = []
        user.access_token = result['access_token']
        graph = GraphAPI(result['access_token'])
        profile = graph.get_object('me')
        posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')
        while True:
            try:
                for post in posts['data']:
                    postss.append(post)
                posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
            except KeyError:
                break
```

But at the end, `postss` list is empty, actually, posts variable is empty!

Problem persists even if user was logged before, so that's not the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ask the user for the permission necessary to access their posts …?

Comment: @CBroe isn't facebook-sdk handling it itself? I haven't found that option in app settings so I'm not sure how to do it properly?

Comment: You need to specify the permissions you want to ask users for in your call of the login dialog. (How to do that with your particular SDK, you’ll need to go research yourself; should be documented I guess.)

Comment: @CBroe Oh I see. I've found that in sdk's github page and added "user_posts" to permissions (they show now when I try to log in using Facebook's login button), but still, my code doesn't work. There's still no posts.

Comment: Output the actual access token that is getting used, and put it through the FB debug tool to see what permissions it includes, or use it to make a request for `/me/posts` in Graph API Explorer – what does that get you?

Comment: @CBroe Actually, problem was in giving right permissions. I have found way to use scope in order to ask user for permission. Please make an answer so I can mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to correct permission to get posts in permission scope. Thanks CBroe.